# ACCESS Select Top 10 Records by COUNT per Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, grouping

I am having trouble with this query in MS Access for Office 365. For each grouping I am trying to select the Top 10 rows by ItemCount. So top 10 ItemName counts will be shown per GroupID. I know the below is wrong because it will only query ten records. I am not sure where to go from here. I tried a subquery that ordered the items then attempted to pull out top 10 items but I obviously did it wrong.

```
Select Top 10 GroupID, ItemName, COUNT(ItemName) as ItemCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY GROUPID, ItemName
Order By COUNT(ItemName) DESC;
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery.  Here is one method:

```
select GroupID, ItemName, count(*) as ItemCount
from Table as t
group by groupid, ItemName
having count(*) in (select top 10 count(*)
                    from table as t2
                    where t2.groupid = t.groupid
                    group by t2.groupid, t2.itemname
                    order by count(*) desc
                   )
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note:  If there are ties, you might get more than 10 rows for a given group.

Comment: I thought this was it but the query gets stuck, no progress bar just endless "Running Query".

Comment: @user3643304 . . . Upgrade your database and use window functions.  Or create a temporary table with the aggregated results.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below, use the TOP keyword in a sub query.

```
Select GroupID, ItemName, COUNT(ItemName) as ItemCount
FROM Table t1
WHERE ItemName in (
                    Select TOP 10 t2.ItemName
                    from Table t2
                    where t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID
                    order by count(t2.ItemName) desc, t2.ItemName
                  )
GROUP BY GROUPID, ItemName
Order By GROUPID, COUNT(ItemName) DESC;
```

Comment: It currently throws an error but I will keep trying. "Invalid Memo, OLE, or hyperlink in subquery 't2.ItemName'.

Comment: @user3643304 never heard the error before, just researched and I think it happens because of the type of "ItemName" column. Is it longtext? Here a solution is offered:
https://improvingsoftware.com/2011/03/15/how-to-join-on-memo-fields-in-microsoft-access/

Comment: yeah it is a long text column. I will look into the memo field thing. thank you.